# Mock unit test async task setup returning null

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a TestMethod async task that is mocking a service setup with ReturnsAsync but for some reason the result keeps returning null.

```
    [TestMethod]
        public async Task GetCustomerAsync_Returns_CustomerResults()
        {
            var customerResults = _fixture.Create<CustomerResults>();

            _mockCustomerService.Setup(s => s.GetCustomerAsync(1)).ReturnsAsync(customerResults);

            var result = await _customerManager.GetCustomerDetails(1);

            Asset.IsNotNull(result);
        }

        public async Task<CustomerResults> GetCustomerDetails(int id)
        {
            var results = await _customerService.GetCustomerAsync(id);
            return results;
        }
```

Comment: What type is `_fixture`? What type is `_mockCustomerService`?

Comment: `it is not working` is a rather broad statement. It does not tell us what is actually happening as apposed to what was expected. You are going to have to provide more context. Too many variables are missing from the provided example for us to be able to effectively help you.

Comment: You’re setting up `_mockCustomerService`, but then calling _customerManager`. What do the two have to do with each other?

Comment: Hey Tim, so the mocked customer service is the customer service so the setup I was expecting would return me from the GetCustomerDetails the returns customerResults.

Comment: John the _fixture is just autofixture creating the CustomerResults object with random values in it.

Answer (score 2):

You should have posted all the code needed to understand the problem, the creation of `_mockCustomerService` and `_fixture` variable, etc.
Having said that i can probably make a guess that you are creating the mockerService and not 'Frezzing' it. The call to _customerManager is not using the _mockCustomerService that you want it to use. You can read about this here [AutoFixture Freeze](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/03/17/AutoFixtureFreeze/)

Comment: cshark thanks that was it when I made it a It.IsAny it worked interesting thanks